# Onclick radio buttons to change background color

Tags: html, css, user-interface

We are displaying two radio buttons in page. Click on Radio buttons, it will change background color.  Is there any way to improve the quality of the code?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .button span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.amber .button span {
  background: #FFC107;
}


.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}

.orange input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #F4511E;
}

.amber input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #FFB300;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<label class="orange">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>

<label class="amber">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="amber">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks pretty good. I only see a couple CSS rules that appear to be useless - for instance:

```
background: #eeeeee;
```

under the ruleset:

```
.button span {
```

But that style is overridden by the background styles under the `<label>` tags (i.e. `.orange .button span` and `.amber .button span`). The only reason I could think that would be needed is if you have other HTML not included in the example above that would have other colors...

---

What is the goal of the styles for `html`? I read the answers to [*Styling the `<html>` element in CSS?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2593106/1575353) and it leads me to believe it is an attempt to avoid scrollbars, but maybe that is incorrect.

---

And is it really necessary to specify

```
background: #ffffff;
```

for the `body` tag? Maybe there are browser settings I am unaware of that allow a user to have a default background color other than that??